# How do I sort HTML Collections based on child elements using plain Javascript?

Tags: javascript

```
   <div class="transaction-row" id= "transaction-row">
        <div class="name">Name 1</div>
        <div class="transaction-type"> Category 1</div>
        <div class="date">Date 1</div>
        <div class="amount">  1738</div>
        <div class="exp-or-inc">Exp or Inc </div>
    </div>

    <div class="transaction-row" id= "transaction-row">
        <div class="name">Name 2</div>
        <div class="transaction-type"> Category 2</div>
        <div class="date">Date 2</div>
        <div class="amount">  50</div>
        <div class="exp-or-inc">Exp or Inc </div>
    </div>
```

What I am trying to do is to sort all of the "transaction row" based on the value in the child element with classname "amount" using javascript. I have been looking for ways to sort multiple dom elements by child elements with sort() and could not find anything.

Edit:

Here is my javascript code:

```
let transEntries = document.getElementsByClassName("transaction-row");
       
let sortedEntries = [].slice.call(transEntries);

sortedEntries.sort((a,b)=> {
     
    if(a.children[3] === b.children[3]) {
            return 0;
    } else {
            return (a.children[3]  < b.children[3]) ? -1 : 1;
    }
       
});
```

I just need it to output a console.log of

```
<div class="amount"> 50</div> 
<div class="amount"> 1738</div>
```

I can figure out how to rearrange the elements. Once I have all the elements stored in an array.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show your research and any attempts you've made. It could be you're close and it would be easier to answer with "just return -1 instead of 0 on line 12" instead of rehashing the whole process.

Comment: If "_HTML Collection_" in the title is [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection), you can't sort the collection. If you just want to sort the elements in a wrapper, collect them into an array, sort the array and append the elements to the wrapper in a loop iterating the array.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). To get the best answers to your question we like to see that you've attempted to solve the problem yourself first using a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Here's a [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) you might find useful...

Comment: Just notices that your ids are the same. They should nbe unique within the document. My answer was the same as Teemu's. Hope this codepen helps https://jsfiddle.net/jmarikle/vxju87nv/

Comment: @Teemu nice to see you man it's been a while .. can you please check my answer it will surprise you !

Comment: `.children[3]` returns an element, you need the number conversions of the trimmed textContent of the elements to compare. Take a look at [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a7j61pqt/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to sort and arrange the items inside an element .... the best way is to do it with CSS ... use `flexbox` on parent and `order` property on its children. Then sort the elements by changing their order using js!

See =>

**HTML**

```
<div id="flex">
  <div class="transaction-row" id="transaction-row">
    <div class="name">
      Name 1
    </div>
    <div class="transaction-type">
      Category 1
    </div>
    <div class="date">
      Date 1
    </div>
    <div class="amount">
      1738
    </div>
    <div class="exp-or-inc">
      Exp or Inc
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="transaction-row" id="transaction-row">
    <div class="name">
      Name 2
    </div>
    <div class="transaction-type">
      Category 2
    </div>
    <div class="date">
      Date 2
    </div>
    <div class="amount">
      50
    </div>
    <div class="exp-or-inc">
      Exp or Inc
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
  #flex {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }

  .transaction-row {
    margin-block: 10px;
  }
```

**Js**

```
  const main = document.querySelector('#flex')
  let main_children = document.querySelectorAll('#flex > *')

  main_children = Array.from(main_children)
  main_children = main_children.sort((a, b) => {
    return   parseInt(a.querySelector('.amount').innerText) - parseInt(b.querySelector('.amount').innerText)
  })
  main_children.forEach((child, index) => child.style.order = index)

  console.log(main_children)
```

**Please note CSS flexbox order property isn't supported by screen readers, they will read them in the order as the HTML has written !**

> Best practice here would be using flexbox .. also never use innerHTML to change the order as it will remove event Listeners and leads to several issues!

Comment: @myriad99a1 Does this answer solves your problem ?

Comment: Yea this works. Very neat too! I learned something new today.

Comment: I would argue this is not the best way because it doesn't change reading order for screen readers. Accessibility is important.

Comment: @Teemu Here see the solution without innerHTML as you said no more eventListeners fading !

Comment: HI @Sanmeet . This works because of `innerText`, it might be more reliable to `trim()` the text content instead, just in case somebody wants to apply the code with a bit different markup ..?

Comment: @Teemu hmmm I already used parseInt() property so using trim () will do nothing I guess ... Correct me if I am wrong !  This answer costs me. - 2 really ?

Comment: @Sanmeet Update your answer to mention about accessibility issue mentioned by Heretic Monkey, and I'll take my downvote back. Even though this is interesting, this is certainly not the best way

Comment: Yes, `innerText` does much the same work as `trim()`, because it returns the text content of the element as it's shown in the layout (leading and trailing white-space is mostly stripped). Parsing to integer might be better to change to a regular number conversion, specifically when you haven't included the radix argument, there might be floats as values too.

Comment: @Utkarsh Dixit hey man updated my answer ! Also can you tell me then what would be a better approach ( keeping screen readers in mind ) ?

Comment: @Sanmeet Idk but a little better approach would be to support DOM level sorting when order property is not supported

Comment: @Utkarsh Dixit Yep I agree with you completly ! But it's also kind of annoying for me as this type of work must be done using backend ( like PHP) not frontend as it leads to performance issues !

Answer (score -1):

As @Teenmu pointed out, assuming you just want to sort out the child elements and all the transaction row share the same parent and that there are no other elements except transaction rows inside their parents, this should work

```js
const transactionRows = [...document.querySelectorAll(".transaction-row")];

let doAllRowsShareSameParent = true;
let lastRowParent = null;

for(row of transactionRows){
  if(lastRowParent && row.parentElement !== lastRowParent){
    doAllRowsShareSameParent = true;
    break;
  }
  lastRowParent = row.parentElement;
}

const parent = lastRowParent;

if(doAllRowsShareSameParent) {
  transactionRows.sort((row1, row2) => {
    const row1Amount = parseFloat(row1.querySelector(".amount").innerText);
    const row2Amount = parseFloat(row2.querySelector(".amount").innerText);
    return  row1Amount - row2Amount;
  }).map(row => {parent.appendChild(row);});
}
```

```html
<div class="transaction-row" id= "transaction-row">
       <div class="name">Name 1</div>
       <div class="transaction-type"> Category 1</div>
       <div class="date">Date 1</div>
       <div class="amount">  1738</div>
       <div class="exp-or-inc">Exp or Inc </div>
 </div>

<div class="transaction-row" id= "transaction-row">
     <div class="name">Name 2</div>
     <div class="transaction-type"> Category 2</div>
     <div class="date">Date 2</div>
     <div class="amount">  50</div>
     <div class="exp-or-inc">Exp or Inc </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps you out

Update: As @Teenmu pointed out, although the previous solution will work with `innerHTML`, it will cause loss of event listeners attached to previous rows. I have updated the logic to fix that.

Comment: Messing with `innerHTML` is an awful solution here, I suggested to _append_ the elements, not to recreating them.

Comment: @Teemu I am confused as to why innerHTML, would be a bad solution here. Assuming the parent doesn't have anything except these transaction rows, there shouldn't be much issue in using `innerHTML`?

Comment: Maybe not on this particular case, but often there are event listeners attached to the elements, setting `innerHTML` would remove all the listeners. Also, why to rebuild the markup, when you already have it, there are a lot of tools with which you can manipulate the DOM without recreating everything.

Comment: @Teemu You are right, I forgot to consider event listeners case. I have updated the answer to fix that

Comment: It looks better, you don't have to remove the element, though, [append](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/append) just moves the element in the tree. You could also remove the useless ids from the markup (and mention it in the text), as they all are having the same value.

Answer (score -2):

```
const transactionRows = document.querySelectorAll('.transaction-row');
const sortedRows = Array.from(transactionRows).sort(sortRowsByAmount);

for (let row of sortedRows) {
  rowsContainer.append(row);
}

function sortRowsByAmount(row1, row2) {
  return getAmount(row1) - getAmount(row2);

  function getAmount(row) {
    return row.querySelector('.amount').innerHTML.trim();
  }
}
```

I didn't test it But it should work

Comment: Isn't simply `appending` the element to the container, also creating duplicates. You'll at least have to clear the previous rows to actually sort out the dom elements

Comment: @UtkarshDixit Nope, `append` doesn't copy an element, it "moves" it.

Comment: Hi Utkarsh, it is correct with new elements, but with existing element in the DOM - ```append``` just move it.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know about this. This makes sense because in theory, a node should have only one parent and since we are not cloning this node, they both have the same reference and so it moves it. Cloning and then appending it should create duplicates

Comment: @UtkarshDixit Yes, cloning and appending a clone would duplicate the element.